# SQLite Query execution condition error

Tags: android, sqlite

SQLite query was not showing the correct answer. What is the error in this query.

```
 "SELECT DISTINCT bike_reg_number from bookings WHERE vendor_id = '"+id+"' AND "+
            "bike_reg_number = '"+temp+"' AND (( from_date > '"+from_dt+"' AND from_date > '"+
             todt+"') OR "+ "(to_date < '"+from_dt+"' AND to_date < '"+todt+"'))";
```

My condition is,

```
(vendor_id must be there) and 
(bike_reg_number must be there) and
(from_date must be > the given both input from_dt and todt) or
(to_date must be < the given both input from_dt and todt)
```

**Edit :**

Many bookings available for a particular vehicle(AA-01-1000). Lets say,

```
(2016-02-06 to 2016-02-06),
(2016-02-11 to 2016-02-11),
(2016-02-15 to 2016-02-16),
(2016-02-19 to 2016-02-20)
```

I wanted to know whether that (AA-01-1000) vehicle is available for(2016-02-08 to 2016-02-09). Now it will return correctly. If I give (2016-02-17 to 2016-02-19) it is showing wrong. Why because only one record is wrong. So the other record true value shows the vehicle number.

Actually I don't want to display vehicle name if any one of the condition fails in bookings table. So, only with sqlite is this possible? Spent more time to fix this bug. Still not fixed.

Comment: sql query seems to be fine but are you sure about the from date and to date condition in query statement.

Comment: I copied the same code and tried in MySql workbench. It is working fine. I debugged and tried, passed date with static values, still condition not working.

Comment: i also tried it in sqlite browser.works fine.may i know the error shown in android

Comment: did you check the from date and to date in sql date format

Comment: No error actually, I am doing some wrong logic. Yes its type was DATETIME

Comment: check fromdate and to date is in format yyyy-MM-dd in stored data

Comment: One booking done for(2016-02-07 to 2016-02-08). Then I am searching for that same vehicle for(2016-02-09 to 2016-02-10) or (2016-02-06 to 2016-02-06). That vehicle needs to appear for booking. But, if I provide the wrong date it should not appear, but it is showing

Comment: My device is not rooted. So I can't check how it was in db. But I am sure the date is stored properly, While saving I am I will check the data and retrieving also date coming properly.

Comment: check the fromdate as you  mentioned 2016-02-07 >2016-02-09 & 2016-02-10 which gives result as false.now todate as  you mentioned as 2016-02-08<2016-02-06 &2016-02-06 which gives result as false so you didn't get booked data

Comment: change From date and to date type as TEXT instead of DATETIME.Sqlite doesn't support DATETIME datatype.

Comment: No, actually condition working fine I checked. My problem is if suppose there are more bookings for a particular vehicle number means, one condition wrong one is true. So it was taking the bike number for true condition. But my problem is if suppose any one condition fails for a vehicle number in bookings table, it should not take that bike number. It is not possible only with SQL query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
"SELECT DISTINCT bike_reg_number from bookings WHERE vendor_id = '" + id +
"' AND bike_reg_number = '" + temp + "'";
```

Retrieved the data and manipulated in java for date comparison. Only with that query I can't do, so I decided to do date comparison with java code.

```
 Cursor cursor1 = db.rawQuery(selectQuery1, null);
    if (cursor1.moveToFirst()) {
        String[] vehicle_number=new String[cursor1.getCount()];
        String[] from_date=new String[cursor1.getCount()];
        String[] to_date=new String[cursor1.getCount()];
        int i=0;
            do {
            vehicle_number[i]=(cursor1.getString(0));
            from_date[i]=(cursor1.getString(1));//dummy
            to_date[i]=(cursor1.getString(2));//dummy
            i++;
            } while (cursor1.moveToNext());
            try {
                String vehi=getDateComparison(vehicle_number,from_date,to_date,from_inp,to_inp);
                VehicleGetSetter contact = new VehicleGetSetter();
                contact.setNumber(vehi);
                contactList1.add(contact);
            } catch (ParseException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    } 

    private String getDateComparison(String[] veh, String[] from, String[] to,String from1, String to1) throws ParseException {
       SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd",Locale.ENGLISH);
       Date table_from,table_to,input_from,input_to;
       long diff=0,diff1=0,diff2=0,diff3=0;
       int count=0,county=0;;
       String vehic="";
       for(int i=0;i<veh.length;i++){
          table_from=df.parse(from[i]);
          table_to=df.parse(to[i]);
          input_from=df.parse(from1);
          input_to=df.parse(to1);
          table_from=df.parse(df.format(table_from));
          table_to=df.parse(df.format(table_to));
          input_from=df.parse(df.format(input_from));
          input_to=df.parse(df.format(input_to));
          diff=table_from.getTime()-input_from.getTime();
          diff1=table_from.getTime()-input_to.getTime();
          diff2=input_from.getTime()-table_to.getTime();
          diff3=input_to.getTime()-table_to.getTime();
          if((diff > 0 && diff1>0) || (diff2 > 0 && diff3>0)){
            count++;
            Log.d("Date", " ok with from");
          }
         else
            county=100;
       }
       if(county==100)
          return vehic;
       else
          vehic= veh[0];

      return vehic;
     }
```